# How dev consoles work?

Tags: ui-design

I want to implement a dev console similar to what is in DOOM.
Is there a standard implementation for dev consoles or would I have to build everything from scratch?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Console-type interface in game](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/32326/console-type-interface-in-game)